# XML/HTML file not listed under Form Properties

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am a newbie to Dynamics 365 and trying to do some customization in the form of some particular Entity. When I am looking (in Form Properties) for the main HTML/XML file , I am unable to find it as there are only js related files. Is there any other location to find my desired file.
Thanks

Comment: What do you suppose this HTML/XML file will allow you to do?

Comment: I want to  customize the view of the form , there should be a html or xml defining the form layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML isnt available. Typically you customise the form using the form editor, e.g. drag and drop. Within Dynamics 365 you don't really get the option to edit the raw HTML of the page.

If you like you can edit the FormXml, but I believe this only gives you the same options as those available via the form editor. To get to the FormXML you either export a solution containing the form or query via the CRM web service. You then have to reverse the process to reimport it. There is no option within form properties for this.

[Editing FormXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328486.aspx)

> FormXml is used to define entity forms and dashboards. The form editor
>   and dashboard designer in the application are the most commonly used
>   tools for this purpose. Editing the customizations.xml file is an
>   alternative method.

[Access form definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334527.aspx#Access%20form%20definitions)

> Entity forms are stored in the SystemForm entity along with dashboards
>   and visualizations. There are two ways that you can inspect the form
>   definitions for an entity:
>
> - Include the entity in an unmanaged solution and export the solution.
> - Query the SystemForm entity

Comment: So here the form based changes will be done from the UI through the form editor?

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani, Yes.

Comment: Thanks James, I can only see js files and also not any server side code. Will not X++ be used for the business logic to connect the models with the objects. Any help on this

Comment: Pretty sure X++ is an AX thing - it doesnt exist in CRM. If you want to write server side code have a look at plugins.